# asp.net checkbox never calls method

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

VS2010

Hello, I have a webpage that contains a gridview populated from a database.  One of the fields is a checkbox.  What I am trying to do is update a value in the database when the checkbox is clicked.  However I have a breakpoint in the `gvSiteInfo_CheckBoxUpdate()` method and it is never reached.

Can you point me in the right direction to get this to work properly?  The few examples I have found on the web appear to be set up like mine.

Below is an abbreviated version of my markup.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSiteInfo" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSorting="gvSiteInfo_Sorting" 
    AllowSorting="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prodHostHeader" HeaderText="Production Host Header" 
            SortExpression="prodHostHeader" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prodDirectory" HeaderText="Production Directory" 
            SortExpression="prodDirectory" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Active Issues" DataField="issueCount"
            SortExpression="issueCount" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Testing Complete" SortExpression="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTestComplete" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="gvSiteInfo_CheckBoxUpdate"
                 Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.testComplete").ToString().Equals("true") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTestComplete" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="gvSiteInfo_CheckBoxUpdate"
                     Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.testComplete").ToString().Equals("true") %>' />             
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code that should be called

```
public void gvSiteInfo_CheckBoxUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SiteDB dbAccess = new SiteDB();
        dbAccess.updateSiteInfo();
}
```

---------------EDIT-----------------------------
Here is my page_load code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        SiteDB dataAccess = new SiteDB();
        dataAccess.SelectedConnectionString = "WISQL01";

        DataTable dt = dataAccess.getSiteInfo();

        gvSiteInfo.DataSource = dt;
        gvSiteInfo.DataBind();
    }
```

-------------UPDATE----------------------------

added `CausesValidation="true"` to `<asp:checkbox>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to recreate grid content (rebind the grid to the data source) on every postback. Since checkbox cell is generated dynamically - it has to be recreated on every postback for event handler to take effect.

Comment: I think I am rebinding every postback.  I have edited my question to include my pageload code which is where i bind the data.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem about binding of your GridView, when you bind for every time, you erase your event.

you must adopt this behavior of binding

```
if(! IsPostBack)
{
  Bind();
}
```

And use `EnableViewState=true` in order to persist your gridview

Comment: `EnableViewState` is set to true for my gridview, and if you look above I added my Page_Load code, and I believe I am rebinding everytime the page reloads.

Comment: perfect Mike i think so you must just adjust your life cycle

Comment: thanks, but I dont know what you mean by adjusting my life cycle.  Is there a property for the gridview or checkbox i need to change?

Comment: No adjust life cycle is just bind your gridview in the good moment, i'am happy to help you

Comment: The data hasnt had a chance to change yet.   the `gvSiteInfo_SelectedIndexChanged` method is never called from the markup even though i have `OnCheckedChanged="gvSiteInfo_CheckBoxUpdate"` set